# i'm trying to insert after <div class="tbox"> and <div class="tarea"> only the latest <div class="properties"> but here every div it is inserted

Tags: jquery

```
<fieldset id="tt">
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" class="pp"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" class="pp"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

```js
$('.cts').find('div:first').each(function(i){
    var attr = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(attr)
    switch(attr) {
        case "tbox":
            $('<div class="fieldProperties">        <input type="text" value="first" name="fields['+i+'].id" id="fields['+i+'].id"> </div>')
                .insertAfter($('.cts').find('div.tbox'));
            break;

        case "tarea":
            $('<div class="fieldProperties">        <input type="text" value="second" name="fields['+i+'].id" id="fields['+i+'].id"></div>')
                .insertAfter($('.cts').find('div.tarea'));
            break;
    }
});
```

Here I'm trying to insert `<div class="properties">` after `<div class="tbox">` and `<div class="tarea">` only the latest `<div class="properties">` but here every div it is inserted. Some field properties are loaded on every time

I'm getting below DOM structure but i don't want like this

```
<fieldset id="tt">
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" class="pp">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[2].id" name="fields[2].id" value="first"></div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[0].id" name="fields[0].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="hidden">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[3].id" name="fields[3].id" value="first"></div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[1].id" name="fields[1].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" class="pp">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[2].id" name="fields[2].id" value="first"></div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[0].id" name="fields[0].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="hidden">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[3].id" name="fields[3].id" value="first"></div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[1].id" name="fields[1].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I'm trying to come the dom structure

```
<fieldset id="tt">
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" class="pp">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[0].id" name="fields[0].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="hidden">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[1].id" name="fields[1].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tbox">
            <input type="text" class="pp">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[2].id" name="fields[2].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cts">
        <div class="tarea">
            <input type="hidden">
        </div><div class="fieldProperties"><input type="text" id="fields[3].id" name="fields[3].id" value="first"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarifying yourself in the comments, I think that's what you're looking for:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/6Byzh/4/)

```
$('.cts').find('div.tbox, div.tarea').each(function(i) {

    var val;

    switch ($(this).attr("class"))
    {
         case ("tbox"):
             val = "first";
             break;
         case ("tarea"):
             val = "second";
             break;
    }

    var properties = 
      $('<div class="fieldProperties">' +
        '<input type="text" value="' + val + '" name="fields['+i+'].id" ' +
        'id="fields['+i+'].id"> </div>');    

    properties.insertAfter(this);
});
```

Comment: it is still not working and all fiels are added on last and it is not following loop

Comment: i sent dom structure , so please find that